# Spring RestTemplate throws always Exception if Http status is 500

Tags: spring

Is it possible to use Spring RestTemplate without using Exceptions to handle http response with status 500?

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            response = restTemplate.getForEntity(probe.getUrl(), String.class);
            boolean isOK = response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK;
            // would be nice if 500 would also stay here
        }
        catch (HttpServerErrorException exc) {
            // but seems only possible to handle here...
        }
```

Comment: How would you handle exception without catch? What are you trying to exactly pull off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a controller using annotation `@ControllerAdvice` if you using springmvc. In the controller write:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpClientErrorException.class)
public String handleXXException(HttpClientErrorException e) {
    log.error("log HttpClientErrorException: ", e);
    return "HttpClientErrorException_message";
}

@ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.class)
public String handleXXException(HttpServerErrorException e) {
    log.error("log HttpServerErrorException: ", e);
    return "HttpServerErrorException_message";
}
...
// catch unknown error
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public String handleException(Exception e) {
    log.error("log unknown error", e);
    return "unknown_error_message";
}
```

and the `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` throw these two kinds of  exceptions:

```
@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    HttpStatus statusCode = getHttpStatusCode(response);
    switch (statusCode.series()) {
        case CLIENT_ERROR:
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(),
                    response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));
        case SERVER_ERROR:
            throw new HttpServerErrorException(statusCode, response.getStatusText(),
                    response.getHeaders(), getResponseBody(response), getCharset(response));
        default:
            throw new RestClientException("Unknown status code [" + statusCode + "]");
    }
}
```

and you can use:`e.getResponseBodyAsString();`，`e.getStatusCode();` blabla in the controller advice to get response message when the exceptions occurs.

Comment: Underwhat class should these configurations fall into?

Comment: @Mike.Chun This should be in the Controller class annotated with     ControllerAdvice

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but you could simply [use a custom `ResponseErrorHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler-) that is not a [`DefaultResponseErrorHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.html), or that extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler but overrides [`hasError()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/DefaultResponseErrorHandler.html#hasError-org.springframework.http.HttpStatus-).